# foldr/foldl on pairs seems to ignore first tuple component

Tags: haskell, ghc, fold, ghci

I just noticed:

```hs
foldr (+) 0 (3,7)
7
foldl (+) 0 (3,7)
7
```

Is this what you'd expect?

What is the rationale behind it?

```
ghci --version 
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.2
```

Comment: A 2-tuple is an instance of foldable, where the first item is seen as a "tag" and the second item as the (only) value. Hence `foldl (+) 0 (3,7)` will only consider `7`.

Comment: `+` operation will have the same effect for foldable anyway, if you go from left to right or vice versa

Comment: What would you expect from `foldr (+) 0 (("hello", True),7)`? Personally, I think tuples should not have been made into foldables, but if they have to be, since they can contain heterogenous data, the only meaningful instance must only consider the last component and ignore the others. This is indeed counterintuitive in the case of a tuple "accidentally" containing homogeneous data. I remember this was discussed several years ago and considered to be a "wat" (surprising behavior) for Haskell.

Comment: Yes, this is a known [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat). The [talk that says it's not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87re_yIQMDw) a wat is delusion IMO: this _is_ silly, unexpected behaviour that should have been prevented by not making tuples `Foldable` at all, much like JavaScript should have prevented the inconsistencies between the various `[] + {}` variations by simply not allowing them at all. It would be better to get the behaviour of this instance by more explicit means, i.e. `snd` / `second` / `Writer` depending on what you want.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I disagree that this is a wat. Consider these two statements: 1. If an instance of class X can be written entirely in terms of an instance of class Y (e.g., `Functor` in terms of `Monad` by `fmap = liftM`), then X should be a superclass of Y. 2. If there's exactly one way that a lawful instance could be written for a given class and type, then that instance should be provided.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Aren't those two statements generally accepted across Haskell programming? And then point 1 supports `Foldable` being a superclass of `Traversable`, point 2 supports `instance Traversable ((,) a)` existing, and together those require that `instance Foldable ((,) a)` exists too.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica the `Traversable` instance is of course just as misplaced as the `Foldable` one. The problem is that morally, there are _two_ equally valid ways in which tuples could be functors, similar to how they are (at least) two equally valid ways in which `Integer` could be a monoid. The fact that one of the sensible tuple-functor instances happens to be impossible to write due to the detail that `(,)` is just a curried type constructor is not a good reason to impose the other one. The proper thing would have been to offer two newtype wrappers, as with `Sum` and `Product`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica TBH I'm not sure it makes sense to use uniqueness for arguing either direction though, since the majority of instances are _not_ unique-possible ones, but rather have a clear convention what behaviour they use or one behaviour that is intuitively obvious. E.g. for lists it's just syntactically natural that we want `[1,2,3]<>[10,11,12] == [1,2,3,10,11,12]` and not `[10,11,12,1,2,3]`. But for tuples, it would be syntactically natural to be symmetric between both sides, which just happens to be impossible with `Functor`...`Traversable`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Re "The problem is that morally, there are two equally valid ways in which tuples could be functors", what's the other way? I can't think of any.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica `fmap' (+1) (10, False) == (11, False)`. AKA `first`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout But `Functor`s need to be functors in their last type parameter, and `(,)` has its fields in the same order as its type parameters.

Comment: Oh I see. You're saying if things were slightly different, then there could be another way it could be a functor. But since that's not the case, what's wrong with imposing the other one?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica that's a bit like saying "due to technical issues that prevented the voices for candidate _A_ from being counted, candidate _B_ becomes president". It's the technical implementation of curried type-constructors in Haskell that makes `fmap`ping over the `fst` impossible, but mathematically the cartesian product / tensor product of a category is profoundly symmetric between both sides.

Comment: Anyway, my beef isn't really about those tuple instances (although the fact that they keep confusing people a lot should remind us that it may not have been the greatest idea), but with the continued attitude of _implementing instances just because we can_. We should implement instances _because the class is an appropriate abstraction_ for a type. If the class is not an appropriate abstraction, then we should seek or write a class that is more appropriate. In case of tuples, `Bifunctor` is the appropriate class, not `Functor`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a bug. The first component of the tuple is part of the "structure" of the tuple, so it isn't altered when `fmap`ping. It's the same with `Either`, the `Left` part is untouched in the same situation.

Some examples of what I mean (I took these from *Haskell Programming from First Principles*):

```
ghci> fmap (+1) (4, 10)
(4,11)
ghci> pure 1 :: Either a Int
Right 1
ghci> pure 1 :: ([a], Int)
([], 1)
```

It might be easier to see that by reading the types:

```
ghci> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b

-- So it expects a Foldable `t b`, where `t` is the structure
ghci> :t foldr (+) 0
foldr (+) 0 :: (Foldable t, Num b) => t b -> b

-- Notice how the String type isn't even mentioned
ghci> :t foldr (+) 0 ("asdf", 1)
foldr (+) 0 ("asdf", 1) :: Num b => b

-- It doesn't touch the first element of the tuple!
ghci>  foldr (+) 0 (undefined, 1)
1
```